# how many apps can i debug on WP devices?

Tags: windows-phone

i am new in WP develop.

i have made 2 apps for WP7 and WP8 and that work well on the emulator, but i want to try it on my HTC 8S

My question is basic, i know after do student  developer unlock to my device i can sideload 3 apps in 3 different devices Windows Phone.

but at any place i can found if 3 sideloads are equals to try 3 apps in debug mode, Not signed and finished apps, just debuging on my devices.

i want to know cause i just have 1 Windows Phone device, but if the debug is not limited quantity i can try my apps on that mode before send to the market place.

Comment: It's three apps at a time and per device. So even if you reach the limit on one device, you can uninstall an old app to install and test the new one.

Answer (score 2):

Student accounts are currently same as Individual accounts and the limit is 10 apps/device. Of course, you can uninstall an app to deploy other one.

> You can deploy up to ten apps on a registered device. This limit does not apply to apps that you install from the Store.

Source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff402565(v=vs.105).aspx

In addition, Microsoft may increase the limit for you, if you send a support ticket explaining why you need to increase it.

Answer (score 0):

You can have 3 apps [in debug mode] deployed on any device single device at any point in time. i.e. 3 apps/device.